# Can not retrieve Third entity from a avtivity in crm 2011 Plugin

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm working on a crm plug in for sending sms.

i have 3 entity in my solution.

first : Activity Entity. this is main entity and user can send sms to multiple contact using this  entity.`(ppp_sms)`

Second: A non activity entity for saving configuration like username and password. `ppp_smsconfiguration`

Third:Another non activity entity for saving sms result. i want to save sms(s), one by one for saving result(s). for example: if user send a sms to 3 contact, he or she should open first Entity, choose the 3 contact, write the message and send it. after sending system will create 3 record in third entity, each record for each contact.

and my problem is: i can retrieve first and second entity information and i can' not retrieve the third entity information.

this is my whole code:
i can not retrieve `ppp_sentsms` entity information

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (serviceProvider == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceProvider");
    }

    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(new Guid?(context.InitiatingUserId));
    ITracingService service2 = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
    QueryExpression expression = new QueryExpression("ppp_smsconfiguration");
    expression.PageInfo.ReturnTotalRecordCount = true;
    ColumnSet set = new ColumnSet();
    set.AllColumns = true;
    expression.ColumnSet = set;
    EntityCollection entitys = service.RetrieveMultiple(expression);

    QueryExpression expression1 = new QueryExpression("ppp_sentsms");
    expression1.PageInfo.ReturnTotalRecordCount = true;
    ColumnSet setSentSMS = new ColumnSet();
    setSentSMS.AllColumns = true;
    expression1.ColumnSet = setSentSMS;
    EntityCollection entitys1 = service.RetrieveMultiple(expression1);

    throw new Exception(entitys1.TotalRecordCount.ToString());

    if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && (context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity))
    {

        Entity entity2 = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

       // Entity preEntity = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["PreImage"];

        this.dbMobileNo.Clear();

        this.dbTo.Clear();
        this.dbMessage = "";

        if (entity2.LogicalName == "ppp_sms")
        {
            QueryExpression expression3 = new QueryExpression("ppp_sms");
            ColumnSet set2 = new ColumnSet();
            set2.AllColumns = true;
            expression3.ColumnSet = set2;
            ConditionExpression item = new ConditionExpression();
            item.AttributeName = "activityid";
            this.CurrentSmsGuid = (Guid)entity2.Attributes["activityid"];
            item.Values.Add(this.CurrentSmsGuid);
            FilterExpression expression5 = new FilterExpression();

            expression5.Conditions.Add(item);
            expression3.Criteria = expression5;
            EntityCollection entitys2 = service.RetrieveMultiple(expression3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code doing?

Answer (score 0):

is that a plugin that is running pre or post creation? 
I suggest you to go on early bound if the query expression are driving you insane.
Remember that sometimes, if the plugin is running in pre creation, you will never be able to retrieve the entities, especially if is running sychronously.